# php - how to assign global value to a static class

Tags: php, static

What is the best way to assign a global value to a static property (from outside of the class)

*( I do not want to use constants (ie define( ... ) ).*

*(since I am using a static class there is no constructor, so I cannot inject the value as an argument)*

---

APPROACH **A** ... WONT WORK ... my preferred approach, but it does not work

```
$my_global = "aaa" ;

class my_class
  { public static $my_prop = $GLOBALS[ 'my_global' ] ; // XXX         
  }
```

---

APPROACH **B** ... WORKS, but feels wrong ... I could use an explicit setter, I know, but then I would have a bunch of one-purpose setters.

```
$my_global = "aaa" ;

my_class::$my_prop = $my_global ; 

class my_class
  { public static $my_prop ;

  }
```

---

APPROACH **C** ... WONT WORK ... using generic setter to assign value to specific property. I would like this approach ok.

```
$my_global = "aaa" ;

my_class::my_setter( "my_prop" , $my_global ) ;  

class my_class
  { private static $my_prop ;

    public static function my_setter( $prop_name , $value )
      { self::$prop_name   = $value ; // XXX
        self[ $prop_name ] = $value ; // XXX
      }
  }
```

---

APPROACH **D** ... WORKS ... using generic setter to assign value in an 'anonymous' registry. I do not like this approach, because I do not know what is in the registry.

```
$my_global = "aaa" ;

my_class::my_setter( "my_prop" , $my_global ) ; 

class my_class
  { private static $my_registry = array() ;

    public static function my_setter( $prop_name , $value )
      { self::$my_registry[ $prop_name ] = $value ;                    
      }
  }
```

Comment: I think it should be `self::$$prop_name = $value;` for Approach C. Also, enabling direct external access to static variables kind of removes the whole encapsulation design of OOP. What is the benefit of a globally write-able static class var vs a global var.

Comment: It can be wrapped by setter/getter in your static class. Do not use public static variable. It's change nothing.

Comment: pleas, stop using global state in your code.

Comment: Philip, thanks for the $$ ... with respect to the question "What is the benefit ...", the answer is that as an author I like cohesiveness.

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward solution is

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $property;
}

MyClass::$property = 'aaa';
```

**CAVEAT**: You should reconsider your choice. Static classes are not a good idea (if fact, they are singletons), since they have negative impact on testability.